# Disabling an app auto-restart on crash (debug build)

Tags: android

I want to disable auto restart of an app in debug builds. Looks like in Android 9.0 and later the app is automatically restarted right after a crash happened. You need to "crash" it twice, to get the app really killed. In this situation "AppName keeps stopping" dialog is displayed by the system.

That's really annoying because when the app stops for the first time, the process is auto-restarted and crash logs are lost.

Any ideas how to disable that 'feature'? Is it some checkbox in Android Studio or Android system settings?

Comment: It can happens if you have a foreground service with return START_STICKY argument in it's onStartCommand()

Comment: @easy_breezy I don't have any services. This happens for new application with just a single activity.